# How i get value from smarty array

Tags: foreach, smarty

This is my variable in array in smarty file
{$CountKey}

The output of this is "**Array**".

I want to get all value from it in smarty file.

Comment: You don't seem to know how variables and arrays work. Just read some documentation: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.tpl

Comment: My foreach loop in smarty not working means i don't able to get the value from this array. {section name=anything loop=$CountKey}
  
 
{/section}

Comment: Sorry but this question is so vague that it's not possible to answer it. Please, read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how to get the array value in smarty..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `foreach` loop to get the values out of an array.

```
{foreach $CountKey as $row}
   <p>{$row.name}</p>
{/foreach}
```

This is very basic knowledge. Please brush up your knowledge on PHP and Smarty.

[Smarty Foreach Documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl)